# How would you properly redraw a widget that displays data from a SQLite database when the data in the database changes?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I store a selected quarter in a Sqlite database. This quarter is displayed in an appbar along with some text a user can click to take them to a page where they can change the selected quarter. Once the user selects a quarter from the page, I push this neq quarter to the sqlite database so it can be displayed. I also use a `Navigator.pop(context);` to go back to the previous page when a new quarter is selected. My problem is that once a user selects a new quarter, the quarter isn't displayed on the page they were just on. You have to navigate away to see it or navigate away and back. the FutureBuilder doesn't seem to know that there is new data in the SQLite database that needs to be displayed. How would I go about making it display the new data when a user selects a new quarter? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

How I display quarters. Also where the button to take you to the page to change quarters is.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
            future: SessionDBProvider.sessionDB.getSessionObject(),
            initialData: List(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    print(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                    );
                  }
              }
              List session = snapshot.data;
              return Container(
                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red],
                                    begin: Alignment.topRight,
                                    end: Alignment.topLeft,
                                    stops: [0.2, 1])),
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11),
                              child: Text(
                                "Test Page",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 27,
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                    height: 1.1),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              "${session[0].selected_quarter}",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 25),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),);
            }));
  }
```

This is where you select a new quarter and push it to the Sqlite database.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(95.0),
          child: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // hides leading widget
            flexibleSpace: DataAppBar(),
          ),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
            future: DataDBProvider.dataDB.getData(),
            initialData: List(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    print(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                    );
                  }
              }
                     List data = snapshot.data;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                          child: Card(
                            color: (index % 2 == 0) ? greycolor : Colors.white,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 60,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                             Data data = new Data();
                                             data.quarter_status = data[index].status;
                                             data.selected_quarter = data[index].quarter;
                                              
                                             DataDBProvider.sessionDB.updateSession(session);
                                              Navigator.pop(context);
                                             },
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                                      child: Text(data[index].quarter,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20,
                                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                              color: Colors.blue),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );

            }));
}}
```

Comment: don't go back to previous page.. reload the same page with new data..  ```Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => YourScreen(new quarter data),),);```

Comment: I have multiple pages, so how would I do that? I reuse the select quarter bit for all of the pages. So I'd need the Navigation to know which page exactly the user was on so it can return back to that page

Comment: do it only when a new quarter is selected by the user. Leave the rest as it is.